# String to org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI to

Tags: eclipse, uri

Exist any possibility to convert java String to org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of static methods on this class for creating URIs such as

```java
public static URI createGenericURI(String scheme, String opaquePart, String fragment);

public static URI createFileURI(String pathName);
```

Comment: Ok, but these methods create URI from file... I want to create URI from String, something like that: Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI("{\"value\" : \"test2\", \"name\" : \"test1\"}"));

Comment: What do you expect the return value `URI.createURI("{\"value\" : \"test2\", \"name\" : \"test1\"}")`? URI has to file path.

Comment: @user3328186 `createGenericURI` creates any type of URI.

Comment: I want to create Resource with string data, I made it in this way:

     Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI(".json"));
        try {
            resource.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes()), options);
        } catch (IOException e) 

    json.getBytes() - return my string

it works fine... but this line:
resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI(".json"));

is very unprofessional (I must put fictitious file name)

Do you have any idea how to omit it ?